# How can I Execute a Function from service program when Windows Fast Startup

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-services

How can I execute a function from service program when Windows 10 Fast Startup. Here is My scenario:

I have windows service program to start some of the exe/function during windows startup.

It works fine in other windows version except windows 10 fast startup.

I have used SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN, SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE and SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE in ServiceMain function, but ServiceMain is not called during fast startup.

If I manually start/stop/pause/continue the service, its working.

Is there any way to create/start a service with service handler for windows fast startup?

Comment: what do you mean by 'fast startup'? is there a slow one?

Comment: @LeiYang he is about this https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/12681d1424033491-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a-cold_hybridboot.png

Comment: As i understood it is kind of hybrid hibernate of old windows, So it will restore previous state of system instead going through all boot process, Then it will not remain fast boot. https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Comment: `ServiceMain is not called during fast startup` - yes, this is must be. when fast startup is used - applications is session 0 (including all services) not terminated. it hibernated when you shutdown and continue run after fast startup. so your service run all time without restart/shutdown. and `ServiceMain` called only once when service started but not after fast startup

Comment: @RbMm I want to clear the log during windows start...so it's not possible in windows fast startup?

Comment: your service *not restarted* but *continue run* when fast startup used. so only way do some task on fast startup - register some notification (I think must be something ) and when you got this notification do your tasks. I think you need call [PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769080(v=vs.85).aspx) function for receive notification about fast startup and clear log file, etc

Comment: or may be you need [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196(v=vs.85).aspx) - read more about [System Power Management Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373223(v=vs.85).aspx) - I not test this with fast startup but sure some events must be. I be on your place register both notification and first simply log in file all events which you got. and view which actually fired during fast startup. after this you can already write actual code for using this event

Comment: in kernel mode drivers can detect exactly fast startup by [Distinguishing Fast Startup from Wake-from-Hibernation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj835779(v=vs.85).aspx) - *The TargetSystemState and EffectiveSystemState bit fields are set to SYSTEM_POWER_STATE enumeration values. If TargetSystemState = PowerSystemHibernate and EffectiveSystemState = PowerSystemHibernate, a wake-from-hibernation occurred. However, if TargetSystemState = PowerSystemHibernate and EffectiveSystemState = PowerSystemShutdown, a fast startup occurred.* but how in user mode don't know

Answer (score 0):

For fast startup,windows terminates user sessions and hibernates session 0 (which contains kernel,drivers,services,etc) when you shutdown and continues run after fast startup.So,the service can't detect shutdown because it has never been stopped or suspended.Unless,you register some notifications or handle session changes.

So you can handle **SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE** control code to do what you want.

For short,check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958801/c-service-doesnt-start-after-windows-shutdown-and-then-boot)